# Won't print all the strings

Tags: c

I can't figure out why when running the code below, it only prints out the first line

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double numb;
    printf("Please enter a decimal place number");
    scanf("%lf", &numb);

    numb = ceil(numb);
    printf("The smallest integer larger than or equal to this value is %f\n", numb);
    numb = floor(numb);
    printf("The largest integer smaller than or equal to this value is %f\n", numb);
    numb = round(numb);
    printf("The nearest integer to this value is %f\n", numb);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` pauses to wait for user input .. are you entering a number (type the number, press Enter)?

Comment: Yeah I'm entering a number

Comment: @RikuEsque: And you're also pressing the ENTER key afterwards?

Comment: you also need to `#include <math.h>` and link in the math library. I assume you're already linking in the math library? .. or it won't even compile

Comment: yup I included that, sorry didn't put it up there

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your actual code. You should always verify that your code actually reproduces the problem before posting it.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/9cfrfzW57)

Comment: You blow away the original value of `numb` the first time you call `ceil`.  So the rest of your printouts don't make sense.  After adding an `#include` of `<math.h>`, and using a second `double` variable `numb2` to hold the results, I got sensible results.

Comment: How do I make it so it prints out for all three (ceil, floor and round)?

Comment: Are you saying it never prints `The nearest integer to this value...` at all??

Comment: @RikuEsque: You should delete the line `numb = ceil(numb);` and change the next line to `printf("The smallest integer larger than or equal to this value is %f\n", ceil(numb) );`. Do the same in the other two places.

Comment: that didn't change it, only "The smallest integer larger than or equal to..." printed out. The other two don't

Comment: nevermind it worked! Thank you very much all of you

Answer (score 1):

Seams like you are trying to compile a C program with math.h library using gcc in Linux. Try using -lm option in command line to compile the code. It will link the math library. Run the example bellow in your terminal to compile. Then run the code.

```
gcc yourFileName.c -o yourFileName -lm
```

*Moreover*, The logic in your code is also seems to be wrong. Please have a look at this statement.

```
numb = ceil(numb);
```

This statement bellow is rewrite the value of `numb` to `ceil(numb)`, which result in printing only the value of `ceil(numb)` in your last three output